# how to connect or configure webstorm with mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, webstorm

I'm testing a simple script inside Webstorm, following the instructions in ["Write Scripts for the Mongo Shell"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/).

But it errors here:

```
conn = new Mongo()
           ^
ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
```

Now, I installed the mongo plugin, and went to "Other Settings" -> "Mongo Servers" and I put the path to the mongo executable.  I also set up the localhost server, and restarted Webstorm.  But I still get this error.

What else do I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: try mongo <yourfile> ?

Comment: ok, but... where in the run configurations do you put 'mongo <yourfile>'?

Comment: oh never mind... i see it.  you run it form the command line in web storm.  thanks for your help :)

Comment: mongo scripts are supposed to be run in mongo shell, and you are likely running them as Node.js applications instead. But Node.js knows nothing about mongo, thus the ReferenceError. If you like to develop NodeJS Mongo applications, you can try mongoose node module (see http://blog.mongodirector.com/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-mongoose/, for example)